# Histogram of a list of matrices for each entry in R

Tags: r, matrix

My function is so complex returning a list of matrices (lower triangular matrices). I would like to get the histogram of the entries of the matrices. That is, for all the matrices, I would like to histogram the values at row 1 and col 1. Then, get the histogram of the entry at the row 1 and col 2 and so on till I get the histogram for each entry.
In another words, suppose that the entries at the row 2 and col 1 in the 3 matrices are as follows:

```
2.4, 3.5, 2.56
```

For example, suppose I have these matrices:

```
mat1 <- c(0, 3, 3, 4, 4,
            0, 0, 3, 4, 5,
            0, 0, 0, 4, 6,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 3,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
mat1 <- matrix(mat1, 5, 5) 


    mat2 <- c(0, 5, 6, 4, 4,
                0, 0, 3, 5, 5,
                0, 0, 0, 6, 6,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 3,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    mat2 <- matrix(mat2, 5, 5)

    mat3 <- c(0, 4, 3.5, 3, 2.9,
             0, 0, 3, 3.9, 3 ,
             0, 0, 0, 3.5, 2.5,
             0, 0, 0, 0, 1.8,
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    mat3 <- matrix(mat3, 5, 5)
```

Then I need to get a histogram for each entry (in total, I should get 10 histograms, since I have 10 element in each matrix (non-zero entries). Any help please?

Comment: There are 15 non-zero entries in matrix mat1! Should there be only entries above the diagonal?

Comment: @Harald , Thank you so much for your comment. No, my matrices are lower triangular.

Comment: @Harald, sorry for mat1, I upload the wrong matrix. I update it now.